# “Wir kaufen ein Geschenk für unsere Tante.” – why “unsere”?

Tags: dative, accusative, possessive-pronoun

> Q) Wir kaufen ein Geschenk für _____ Tante.
>
> 1. unserer
> 2. unsere
> 3. unseren

I came across this question on an app that I am using to practice German. I thought Option 1 is correct because *Tante* is an indirect object and thus should be in the dative case.
However, the app says the correct answer is Option 2.
Can somebody please explain it to me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where should a direct and indirect object be placed in a Nebensatz?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/52850/where-should-a-direct-and-indirect-object-be-placed-in-a-nebensatz)

Comment: Comments deleted; please be nice. Also note that it doesn’t even matter whether this is homework or not. The asker is not simply asking for us to do their homework – after all they already know the answer. Instead they are elaborating their thoughts and want to know where they went wrong. This is how questions should be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The preposition *für* requires the Akkusativ. See here:

[image]

[Source](https://deutschlernendlv.wordpress.com/10-vg-vp/prapositionen-mit-dativ-und-akkusativ/)

Thus the correct answer is indeed *für unsere Tante*.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and explaining to me the answer. The app did give the correct answer, I just needed an explanation(why). I am a beginner and i do get confused even with the basics but it is important to understand the exceptions as well. Thanks all :)

Comment: No worries. Your questions are very welcome here - please feel free to ask more! I definitely recommend using a grammar book in addition to the app, as most apps will not cover grammar exhaustively.