# Accusative and dative differences

Tags: dative, accusative

I'm currently learning German and there are some issues in fully understanding accusative and dative forms.

Example 1:

> Sie hat ein Sofa, einen Stuhl und einen Sessel **ins** Zimmer
> gestellt.

So, **by our coursebook** this is Accusative

Example 2:

> Zwischen **dem Sofa** und **dem Sessel** hat sie einen Tisch gestellt.

**By our coursebook** this is Dative

So, I have trouble understanding why 2<sup>nd</sup> sentence is dative as it looks like we can rearrange it and rewrite it to be same like first one (as accusative).

> Sie hat einen Tisch zwischen **das Sofa** und **den Sessel** gestellt.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you check whether your book actually contains the second example? It looks wrong. (Also, what book is that?)

Comment: pardon me, it was workbook which we solved as a group with teacher. This is something that we discussed on a class but didnt reach an agreement

Comment: Suppose *Sofa* may be masc.? It is tylically neuter and requires *das* in either case.

Comment: For me, the second example is not correct. It should be accusative, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Not the whole sentence is in any case, only some parts of it are in a case. Here is an example where all 4 cases appear in just one sentences:

> Elisabeths Eltern glauben ihrer Tochter die Ausrede.

- Elisabeths Eltern
  Subject in **nominative** case
- Elisabeths
  **Genitive** Attribute of the noun *Eltern*
- ihrer Tochter
  **Dative** object of the verb *glauben*
- die Ausrede
  **Accusative** object of the verb *glauben*

---

This sentence is wrong:

> <del>*Zwischen dem Sofa und dem Sessel hat sie einen Tisch gestellt.*</del>

These are correct sentences:

> Zwischen dem Sofa und dem Sessel hat sie einen Tisch stehen.
> <sup>She has a table between the sofa and the chair.</sup>
> Zwischen dem Sofa und dem Sessel hat sie einen Tisch aufgestellt.
> <sup>She has set up a table between the sofa and the chair.</sup>
> Zwischen das Sofa und den Sessel hat sie einen Tisch gestellt.
> <sup>She put a table between the sofa and the chair.</sup>

The main difference between dative and accusative case is this:

- Dative case describes a place, not a direction.
- Accusative case describes a direction, not a place.

So, when ever you move something into a certain direction (for example between some other furnitures) you need to have this direction in accusative case:

> Jürgen stellt die Lampe auf **den Tisch.**
> <sup>Jürgen puts the lamp on the table.</sup>
> Ilse legt das Hemd in **den Koffer.**
> <sup>Ilse puts the shirt in the suitcase.</sup>

But when you describe, that something is at a certain place, you have to use dative case:

> Die Lampe steht auf **dem Tisch.**
> <sup>The lamp is on the table.</sup>
> Das Hemd liegt in **dem Koffer.**
> <sup>The shirt is in the suitcase.</sup>

Wenn you move the table between sofa and chair, then you describe a direction and then you need accusative case:

> Zwischen **das Sofa** und **den Sessel** hat sie einen Tisch gestellt.
> <sup>She put a table between the sofa and the chair.</sup>

This is because the verb *stellen* describes a movement into a direction.

But the verb *aufstellen* (to mount, to erect, to assemble) means that you assemble the table at a given place, i.e. not into a direction., and the verb *stehen* means, that it stands at a given place, i.e. not into a direction. So, for *stehen* and *aufstellen* you need dative case.

> Zwischen dem Sofa und dem Sessel hat sie einen Tisch stehen.
> <sup>She has a table between the sofa and the chair.</sup>
> Zwischen dem Sofa und dem Sessel hat sie einen Tisch aufgestellt.
> <sup>She has set up a table between the sofa and the chair.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. It is possible to rephrase it like you did. In German we differentiate between where something is (Dativ, with related question: Wo?) and where we like to put something (Akkusativ, with related question: Wohin?). As you can see there is no difference in English, neither in other languages like Italian.

Another example: Wo bist du? Ich bin bei meinem Freund. Where are you? I'm at/with my friend. This is Dativ in German. But when I ask: Wohin gehst du? Ich besuche meinen Freund. In this case it's Akkusativ. Where do you go? I'm going to visit my friend. Wohin asks for a direction to, not for a place.

Since there is no equivalent in English, you have to simply learn it.

Answer (score 0):

The examples are insufficient and, as David pointed out, probably wrong in the second example.

The articles may be deictic (*Er hat die Antwort gegen* die *Wand gefahren*, *du bellst* den *falschen Baum an*) and they may be otherwise left out, if the referents are already known in at least a abstract sense (*zwischen Tür und Angel*).

The difference between akkusativ and dativ only makes sense in your last example, to distinguish the object types (traditional grammar speaks of direct and indirect objects, *ich geben ihn ihm*, i.e. *einem Hund einen Knochen*). This typing has to agree across texts even if no ambiguity exists in the single clause such as in your first example.

In the second example, *stellen* could be in principle from an mono-transitive sense akin to *herstellen*, whereby the zwischen-phrase would be chiefly adverbial, predicative but no argument. This would very unusual and typically used only to mock broken grammar, but it is in agreement with the stellen-stehen distinction (*Ich stelle mich zwischen einen...; Ich stehe zwischen einem Stuhl und einem Tisch*). This distinction is not frequently observed for "stellen" and would be perceived as embedding of a relative clause as preposition (*zwischen dem Sofa und dem Tisch [stehend]*, i.e. *während ich zwischen dem Sofa und dem Tisch stehe*).

Comment: I find this answer more confusing than helpful. Mentioning direct and indirect objects, which are typically considered as non applicable in German, see [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/52850/1696), further increases confusion.

Comment: @Guido, it makes a lot of sense to distinguish *dem Hund* as somehow inferior, because it usually cannot appear alone in this phrase (*Gib Ihm*, is a rare exception), and indirect aappears as a plausible choice. There are many other ways where it maybe is less usefull. Calling it dative object explains very little anyhow, but should yield positive hits in a web search, agreed.